# The requested URL was not found on this server for flask application

Tags: apache, flask, deployment, vps

I don't know that why its not working? I configurated step by step my Flask website but it doesn't work yet. so I have a **404 not Found** error on my website

**FlaskApp.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *>
                ServerName croyal.net
                ServerAdmin my@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All 
            Require all granted
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
            Require all granted
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys 
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr) 
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/") 
from FlaskApp import app as application 
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

Comment: What command do you execute that leads to the 404

Comment: And how is the code for the route you try to reach?